# PHP getting str_replace to work with a GET request?

Tags: php

So, Jessica was kind enough to help me last time.

```
<?php
$string = 'hi+';
if(strpos($string, '+') !== false){
$string = str_replace('+', 'test', $string);
}
echo $string;
?>
```

Would basically work, however changing $string to a GET request like `$string = $_GET['s'];` and testing that would not take the + as user input (would just be blank). How would I fix this? Would it work with POST?

Comment: var_dump($_GET) and show us the result, is there anything coming through at all?

Comment: The `+` in the URL are automatically converted to spaces beforehand. You are looking for `QUERY_STRING`. Or might have to explain the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if your url's aren't properly encoded, you can force encoding and you get desired result. 
Something like that should work:

```
<?php

$string = urlencode($_GET['s']);
if(strpos($string, '+') !== false){
  $string = str_replace('+', 'test', $string);
}

echo $string;
```

But i say: the correct way is decoding the encoded URL, not doing reverse (encoding to get the raw URL from already decoded one.)

Comment: if (isset($_POST['Build1']))
{
$string = urlencode($_POST['pool']);
if(strpos($string, '+') !== false){
$string = str_replace('+', '%2B', $string);
}
echo $string;
echo 'iejeijfejiwfj';
file_get_contents('.php?pool=' . $_POST['pool'] . '&user=' . $_POST['user'] . '&pass=' . $_POST['pass']);
echo "Successful";
header('Location: t');
}
else
{
} // Is not working, not even echoing iejeijfejiwfj what's wrong here? It works via localhost (w/o the implementation to my site)

Comment: Tell me the content of **_POST**, create gist or use pastebin, please.

Comment: The param is already encoded. `$string` is already with %2B, and try displaying errors using: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL)` at top.

Answer (score 2):

When in a `GET` parameter, the `+` gets [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/urlencode)d as `%2B`. When grabbing it from the query string, you need to [`urldecode`](https://www.php.net/urldecode) it.:

```
$string = urldecode($_GET['s']);
```

[**Example**](http://codepad.org/STUQjAl7)

Comment: Would I still have to use uldecode & encode if I used a POST request?